# What's the easiest way to loop out values of string[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops

So, let's say that I have a `string[] { "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth" };` called "a".

And you want to loop out the values of it. Of course, you could use foreach-loop, that's probably the easiest.

```
foreach (string i in a)
{
    Console.Write(i + ", ");
}
```

This would output the following: First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth,

Notice that the last index has a comma after it. Now, how would you loop the same way, leaving the last index without a comma and a white space?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string result = String.Join(", ", a);
```

Comment: aargh!! You're way too fast!

Comment: That was fast, sir. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, what if I wanted to put a full stop after the last index?

Comment: @Tatu `String.Join(..) + "."`?

Comment: @Tatu: for example `string result = string.Format("{0}.", string.Join(", ", a));` or what Silvermind has suggested, simple string concatenation.

Comment: @Silvermind I didn't even think of that, haha. Well, it works, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need looping at all. A simple `string.Join` would do.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", a));
```